# Can I configure an Arduino via NFC using PN532 with an iPhone as the source?

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit, nfc

It seems clear that Apple has intentionally limited the possibilities with NFC, so I understand that I'm going against the grain here. However, I need to support Android and Apple for my device setup, so I'm hoping to work around the Apple restrictions by making my Arduino receive data from an iPhone by posing as an RFID card and accepting a write from my Adafruit PN532 breakout board. I've got my Arduino Uno connected to the board and successfully reading from RFID cards. So the question is can I do a read from an iPhone? I've been experimenting with NFCTools on my iPhone to see if I can stimulate any behavior on my Arduino by running the Adafruit example programs and putting my phone near the reader while activating a write. I haven't had any success yet.

My idea is to avoid requiring Bluetooth for Arduino setup. My configuration is very simple so I don't need anything with high bandwidth. The configuration is done rarely and always by a person who is nearby. It seems like leaving out Bluetooth capability out of my device will save on cost and power consumption (though I don't know how much). It would be really slick too since my customer wouldn't need to go into settings to connect with Bluetooth. Instead they just put their phone near the device and it gets configured!

Comment: so, you are asking if your iPhone is able to pose as an RFID card ... wouldn't that be a question for the iPhone crowd?

Comment: I'm asking in two directions-- can the iPhone be a Card for read purposes, or can the PN532 be a card for Write purposes. Anyway, I did some more research and it looks like BLE is a better connectivity solution for my needs and still has the magic feel of appearing in an app without going into Settings and explicitly connecting.

Comment: `can the iPhone be a Card for read purposes?` is not about arduino, so it is off topic here ... `can the PN532 be a card for Write purpose` is also not about arduino ... you may have a better chance of a good answer at a Adafruit forum

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the PN532 is a reader/writer and will only want to communicate with passive nfc devices (an RFID card). Therefore, with a phone you cannot really communicate between the two in the way you want. Basically both your phone and the PN532 are going to only look for a passive device.